# Can I use FTP to replace images on a ColdFusion site?

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, ftp

I have a site that needed a few cosmetic changes such as the logo and the a background image for a button. I FTPd in and replaced the images with new ones of the exact same name and dimensions (no changes to any files except the images).

There's a jQuery banner on the site now (seemingly unrelated to the images that I changed) that isn't functioning properly.

Is this a result of changing out the images? Is there some weird seal that I broke accessing this ColdFusion website? I know that my actions wouldn't have broken anything on an HTML based site, but ColdFusion is something foreign to me. Do I need to do something to fix this related to ColdFusion, or do I need to start looking at the jQuery slider for something that broke coincidentally?

Thanks!

edit: Javascript console information:

The jQuery files that handle the slider show this error:  Failed to load resource: Server responded with a status of 500 (URL Module Rewrite Error).

Update 2: Turns out there was a server problem elsewhere that was causing this, and the breakage was a coincidence. Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: "start looking at the jQuery slider for something that broke coincidentally" +1

Comment: I would start with opening Firebug at the page with not functioning banner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Looking at the CF server logs, also you can try a restart of the CF service if that is happening again? sometimes GC issues might show 500

This post gives you more clues
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/84-500-null-Mysterious-ColdFusion-Error.htm

Edit: Ignore above
Looks like your URL module error is from IIS not from CF.. Common answers which Google gives is to reinstall the URL rewrite module.

Since firebug shows you this error, you can also confirm that by pasting the JS url directly on the browser.

Would suggest looking into the IIS config/logs.

Comment: Definitely see if you can view the image directly. It might've just been corrupted during transfer.